# Invisible scatter plane in final render, how?

Tags: rendering

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot I am trying to create an asteroid ring around this planet.

I tried to simply use an empty circle and scatter a set of asteroids around it but it did not work.  My idea is that the circle would not show in the final render.

Now I am trying to scatter around a plane circle.  The scatter worked but the circle shows in the final render and if I disable it in the render even the asteroids disappear.  Is there a way to make the plane circle only disappear?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Are you using particle system or geometry nodes to scatter?

Comment: If you're using particle system you can hide the emitter (Particle System panel > Render > Show Emitter)